# AWS EMR Automated Failover to another EMR Cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, emr, high-availability

We are currently working on Standing Up an EMR Cluster for one of our Applications and since we want the EMR Setup to be resilient, we want to create a StandBy EMR cluster in an AZ different from the Primary EMR Cluster AZ. However we are not sure how to automate the Failover to the Secondary EMR if the Primary EMR Cluster AZ goes down.

Any thought's?

Answer (score 2):

EMR supports HA from may 2019 [1]

[1] https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/04/amazon-emr-announces-support-for-multiple-master-nodes-to-enable-high-availability-for-EMR-applications/

Comment: How can we recover a AZ failure for AWS EMR ?

Answer (score 0):

Currently EMR Doesn't support High availability.  As EMR works with Data in S3 using EMRFS you can have your Data stored reliably in s3 even if AZ of EMR goes down your data is persisted safely in s3.

EMR supports Cloud-watch Event which can trigger sns notification for cluster status change. You can use the same to start new cluster in another AZ.

Answer (score 0):

That won't be needed. EMR by design would issue a new worker or task node if they fail. For the Master node, you have access to all detailed Cloud Watch services as mentioned earlier and one solution would be to set up a Lambda service that provisions a new cluster if your Master Node fails. 
As mentioned in other answers, your data persistence is a separate issue but for the most part and by default EMR storage resides on S3 buckets (available to all zones and highest data persistence).